# Bind dynamically made widgets to one signal in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, signals, pyqt5

I have a frame to which layout I dynamically add lineedits clicking on a toolbutton. I need all of these lineedits to work with my autocompleter on signal `textChanged`.
I can't quite understand how to do it. I saw while researching that `lambda` may help but I couldnt't do it. I guess it's because I poorly understand how all this works. I used QtDesigner and [this](http://1.pyqtforlinguists.appspot.com/ebook/_2____pyqt5.html) tutorial to make GUI. My code is in two files - in the first there are just widgets:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(799, 424)
        ...
        self.toolbutton_add_score = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.groupbox_scores)
        self.toolbutton_add_score.setObjectName("toolbutton_add_score")
        self.layout_groupbox_scores.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.toolbutton_add_score)
        self.frame_movies_scores = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.groupbox_scores)
        self.frame_movies_scores.setObjectName("frame_movies_scores")
        self.layout_frame_movies_scores = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_movies_scores)
        self.layout_frame_movies_scores.setObjectName("layout_frame_movies_scores")
        self.lineedit_input_movie = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_movies_scores)
        self.lineedit_input_movie.setObjectName("lineedit_input_movie")
        self.layout_frame_movies_scores.addWidget(self.lineedit_input_movie, 0, 0)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Рекомендательная система"))
        ...
```

In the second one there are my functions:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineedit_input_movie.textChanged.connect(self.autocomplete)
        self.ui.toolbutton_add_score.clicked.connect(self.add_score_field)

    def autocomplete(self):
        cursor.execute("SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%%' || %s || '%%';", (self.ui.lineedit_input_movie.text(),))
        it = cursor.fetchall()
        strings = [item[0] for item in it]
        completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(strings, self)
        self.ui.lineedit_input_movie.setCompleter(completer)
        self.ui.lineedit_input_movie.show()

    def add_score_field(self):
        self.lineedit_input_movie = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.ui.frame_movies_scores)
        self.lineedit_input_movie.setObjectName("lineedit_input_movie")
        self.ui.layout_frame_movies_scores.addWidget(self.lineedit_input_movie, r, 0)
```

The code here works only for the fiers lineedit in layout. What do I have to do to make it work for all lineedits in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your additional fields in a list to keep their references. At the moment you are overwriting your existing field which is not good. Also you need to connect your `textChanged` signal for each new field.

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        self.score_fields = []
        # ...


    def add_score_field(self):

        # Create a new Line Edi
        new_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.ui.frame_movies_scores)
        new_lineedit.setObjectName("lineedit_input_movie")

        # append it to your score_fields list
        self.score_fields.append(new_lineedit)

        # add it to your layout
        self.ui.layout_frame_movies_scores.addWidget(new_lineedit, r, 0)

        # connect your signal
        new_lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.autocomplete)
```

Comment: Actually I already tried something like that before and it didn't worked. Anyway I tried your solution and it doesn't work as well. I have a feeling like the program doesn't make connections when you try to do it from functions.
Moreover, PyCharm is warning me "Unresolved attribute reference 'connect' for class 'pyqtBoundSignal" on this line:
`new_lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.autocomplete)`

Comment: I guess I wasn't right in my comment. Actually, making connections work from inside functions. But what isn't right in my program now is how autocomplete works: I have to somehow give this function the lineedit that is currently used. I tried to google to make connectons with arguments but didn't quite understood. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Your autocomplete function currently uses `self.ui.lineedit_input_movie` to apply your changes. You need to pass the sender object to your function. Use `self.sender()` instead.